# What is the name of the Beamer color theme that produces a light blue background color like in the official documentation

Tags: beamer

Is there a beamer theme or a beamer color theme that produces the bakground color like in the following picture that is taken from the official documentation ? 
thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\title{There Is No Largest Prime Number}

\subtitle{With an introduction to a new proof technique}

\author{Euclid of Alexandria}

\institute{Department of Mathematics\\University of Alexandria}

\date[ISPN ’80]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers, -280}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage

\begin{block}{Results}
Proof of the Main Theorem
\end {block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just add `\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=lightgray}` after `\documentclass`. See `beameruserguide` section 8.2.7

Comment: @BambOo thank you for your reply but the question is "What is the name of the beamer/color theme" if It exists

Comment: While I may be wrong, but after a quick search in the documentation source code, I could not find any reference to a specific theme

Comment: The thing is that for instance the first example picture is obtained with `\pgfimage[width=.45\textwidth,page=2]{beamerugthemePittsburgh}`. However, there is no `beamerugthemePittsburgh` in the whole package directory, so I wonder how this works

Comment: @BambOo I am very impressed by your tenacity.  Your finding is very interesting.  Tank you

Comment: If you really want a precise answer, I think you should ask the maintainers directly (mail or maybe on the chat)